# Can't load mcrypt.dll dynamic library

Tags: configuration, module, php

I'm trying to load this module: php_mcrypt.dll'
Everything in the php.ini file is correct, see for yourself:

```
extension_dir = "C:/PHP/5.2.13/ext"
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

The file exists in this path. And other modules are in there as well and are loaded successfully. It only has a problem with this particular module.

I have a 64bit Windows XP, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.2.13...

But i get this warning (error.log of Apache):
**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/PHP/5.2.13/ext\php_mcrypt1.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0**

PHP itself is working fine. But one of our applications needs this module and it throws me this ugly error. Why on earth does it show me two backslashes in the log file?

Comment: I think you can ignore the backslashes: The "line 0" message is usually a symptom for a 32-bit/64-bit problem or a version conflict. Which versions of Apache and PHP are you using? (Do they have 64-bit versions at all?)

Comment: sorry for my late reply, but I had to head home. I am using Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'C:/PHP/5.2.13/ext\php_mcrypt1.dll'

I'd say there's some typo on your `php.ini` (the extra `1`). Perhaps you're loading a different `php.ini` from what you expect (see the output of `php.ini` to make sure).

Other than that make sure that `php_mcrypt.dll` and PHP:

- Were linked to the same VC runtime library (typically msvcrt.dll for VC6 or msvcrt90.dll for VC9) – use e.g. the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for this
- Are both debug builds or both release builds
- Both have ZTS enabled or ZTS disabled
- For libraries that depend on further libraries (DLLs), make sure they are available (e.g. in the same directory as the extension)

PHP should give you meaning errors if any of the first three conditions above is not satisfied, but I wrote those anyway because I'm not sure for PHP 5.2.

Comment: could you please look into this issues in windows 10 https://prnt.sc/kcwqq3

Answer (score 1):

Guys, I found the solution!

Thank god for this article!
http://blogs.iis.net/donraman/archive/2009/10/16/configuring-php-extension-on-windows-a-simple-way.aspx

---

There has been too many problem reported in our forum about not able to configure one particular extension. The problems are many:

```
* Configuring a non-compatible version of the extension
* Missing some dependent DLL
* Trying to use thread safe version of the extension DLL  for non thread safe PHP build and vice-versa
```

So, I basically installed PHP in a different directory using the PHP MSI installer, which can be found here: http://windows.php.net/download/. I only installed PHP, without the Apache Server, and selected the mcrypt extension. After the installation was done, I copied the dll file into my real PHP directory, restarted Apache and it worked!

Comment: I was trying to find mcrypt.dll and this finally worked. To be sure, go for one of the oldest releases available. 5.2.11 installer had what I needed, but a more recent 5.3 version didn't.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure there is 64bit version of libmcrypt.dll available to download out there
the problem unable to load the php_mcrypt.dll extension based on dependency of libmcrypt.dll

1. download libmcrypt.dll from following link
   http://files.edin.dk/php/win32/mcrypt/
2. copy and paste it into apache/bin/ eg:(C:\Program Files\Apache\bin)
3. uncomment extension=php_mcrypt.dll and extension=php_mcrypt_filter.dll
4. restart your apache web server using
   (C:\Program Files\Apache\bin\ApacheMonitor.exe)

for 32 bit windows computer with apache web server installed will work
at least it works well on my windows 2003 server with Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6

good for drupal6,wordpress,magento and a lot of cms using php :)

Answer (score 0):

Go back to php.ini and change

extension_dir = "c:/php/ext"

to

extension_dir = "C:\php\ext\"

Then restart the server and try her again.